# TeamCity build: Module A depends on Module B, but failed to pick up the change in Module B

Tags: java, git, teamcity

I have two modules in my project, module A depends on module B, more specifically, A depends on a domain class in B.

Now I added a new property to the said domain class in module B, as well as its getter/setter. I built module B on TeamCity. Then I tried to build module A on TeamCity as well. It failed, citing that the getter/setter of the said property weren't found.

Both A and B are from the same **git** feature branch, and the building happened within that branch.

Why the change in B (newly-added property and getter/setter) weren't picked up by the invoking client in module A? TeamCity 2021.2.